# Is a clause beginning with "where" an adjective or adverb clause?

Tags: adverbs

I was looking for adverbial clause examples and found this: **We’ll go to the bar where they asked us to wait.**

I think it's an **adjective clause since** "**bar**" was mentioned. It is describing the place; I think if it were: **We will go (to) where they asked us to wait**, it would be an adverbial clause; however, since there is a noun that is being described, it is no longer an adverbial clause. I take my conclusions by inverting the placement of the sentences, since in adverbial clauses we can use both dependent or independent clauses in the beginning:

**Adjective Clause:**

> Where they asked us to wait, we will go to the bar
>
> We will go to the bar where they asked us to wait.

**Adverbial Clause:**

> Where they asked us to wait, we will go (to)
>
> We will go (to) where they asked us to wait

Or, could it be used in both forms, meaning both things?

Comment: You are right. "where they asked us to wait" is an adjective clause in the sentence where the main clause is "We'll go to the bar" and an adverbial clause of place in the sentence whehre the main clause is "We'll go".

Comment: The syntax lawyers like to drag out the law books on stuff like this and attach weird terms to the phrases, so can't give you the final word on what it is "called".  But definitely, the "where they..." clause is being *used* as an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *We’ll go to the bar [where they asked us to wait].*

The bracketed element is a relative clause modifying “bar”, where relative word “where” is functioning as an adjunct of place. We understand that *they asked us to wait in/at that bar.*

> [2] *We’ll go (to) [where they asked us to wait].*

Again, this is a relative construction, but of a special kind, called a “fused relative”. It gets that name from the fact that the antecedent and the relative word are fused together into the single word "where", with the sense "the place where". This time the bracketed element is a noun phrase with "where" as fused head. It is comparable to "We’ll go to the place where they asked us to wait". Semantically, then, it is very similar to [1].

Comment: Sorry for perhaps asking a silly question, but isn't *where they asked us to wait* a preposition phrase? [+1 for everything else, but that bit's confusing me ..]

Comment: Reason I'm asking is because it says it is an NP, not a PP in your penultimate sentence ... :)

Comment: Ah, you're referring to [2] only; I wasn't sure if you meant in both examples. I think the prep "to" is causing confusion. If it is included, I take the bracketed constituent to be an NP as its complement. If "to" is omitted, I agree with you, it is a PP.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I just meant in (2). Even if *to* is included couldn't it be taking a *where* PP as complement? Is there a pronoun *where* in English to make an NP out of? (I don't know the answer to that question!)

Comment: I think it all boils down to whether _where they asked us to wait_ in [2] can be an NP as complement to the overt prep "to". CGEL p1068 [1] iiia predictably gives "I'll go _where you go_" as a PP. And p1070 [8] vi gives an example with fused "what" as comp of prep "of" ("I was ashamed **of** _what I had done_") and I assume that analysis would also apply to fused "where", as in "I was ashamed **of** _where I had been_". Let me check on that.